# Why a superconductor expel magnetic lines of force from inside completely when cooled below critical temperature?

Tags: magnetic-fields, temperature, superconductivity, phase-transition

Suppose a [superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) which is in a normal state (i.e. $T>Tc$) is subjected to a magnetic field. As soon as magnetic field switched from 0 to some value, eddy currents will develop on the surface and they will die away because of finite resistance. Now if I decrease the temperature below critical temperature, normal material will become superconductor and it will expel the magnetic field immediately, cf. the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect). I want to know the reason what causes the superconductor to push away magnetic fields.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_equations ?

Comment: Yes I did. I have gone through London's original paper. However, I think it do not explain why magnetic filed push out from inside.  It will you how magnetic filed will penetrate a superconductor and proves that magnetic filed could not live inside a superconductor mathematically. But why.. the physical reason remained un-explained.  I would be happy if you explain it to me

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the reason what causes the superconductor to push away
>   magnetic fields.

The underlying assumption for [London equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_equations), describing [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect#Explanation), is that the transition to the superconducting state is associated with "setting up electric currents near its surface".

So, the magnetic field is pushed out of a superconductor by the currents flowing near its surface. Not sure if there exists a consensus on how exactly these currents are generated, though.

Comment: I think there is. Supposedly the BCS theory contains the reason.

Comment: @coniferous_smellerULPBG-W8ZgjR There are some papers (like this: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ec22/0d13c54f75ada314bfd2accf3d4c2d5b2296.pdf) that specifically question whether BCS correctly explains Meissner effect. I have no idea how credible they are, but thought to mention it.